# concat a SPLIT variable in R

Tags: r, split, concatenation

I've been trying to split a string in R and then joining it back together but none of the tricks have worked for what I need.

!!!**Important** !!! My question is not a duplicate:

saving a *split* result into a variable and then pasting, collapsing etc is not the same as just paste a vector like this

paste(c("bla", "bla"), collapse = " ")

```
> paste(c("The","birch", "canoe"), collapse = ' ')
[1] "The birch canoe"
> paste(s, collapse=" ")
[1] "c(\"The\", \"birch\", \"canoe\", \"slid\", \"on\", \"the\", \"smooth\", \"planks.\")"
```

Here's the code:

I take pre-saved sentences in R

sentences[1]
and split it

s <- str_split(sentences[1])
this is what I get:

```
[1] "The"     "birch"   "canoe"   "slid"    "on"      "the"     "smooth"  "planks."
Now when I try to join this back together I get backslashes

toString(s) 

"c(\"The\", \"birch\", \"canoe\", \"slid\", \"on\", \"the\", \"smooth\", \"planks.\")"
paste produces the same result:

> paste(s)
[1] "c(\"The\", \"birch\", \"canoe\", \"slid\", \"on\", \"the\", \"smooth\", \"planks.\")"
```

I tried using str_split_fixed and wrap it into a vector, but it joins the sentence back together with a comma, even if I ask it not to.

```
v <- as.vector(str_split_fixed(sentences[1], " ", 5))
toString(v, sep="")

[1] "The, birch, canoe, slid, on the smooth planks."
```

I thought maybe str_split_i or str_split_1 could solve it as according to the documentation in theory it should, but that's what I get when I try to use it

"could not find function "str_split_1" "
Are there any other ways to join back a string after splitting it without it producing commas or backslashes?..

Comment: `str_split` produces a `list` output - in this case of length 1. So try using `s[[1]]` rather than `s` in your `paste` statement.

Comment: `toString(s[[1]])`

Comment: How about `sentences = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit";
s <- strsplit(sentences[1], split=" "); s;
paste0(sentences[1])`?

Comment: toString(s[[1]]) adds a comma between the split parts.

Comment: paste(sentences[1]) doesn't solve the problem at all :) because the trick is to re-assemble the value saved in the variable rather than just getting back to the initial sentence. I wouldn't have to concatenate it at all, because in sentences[1] it is already contained in the version i need))

Answer (score 2):

See the difference between:

```r
s <- list(c("The"  ,  "birch" ,  "canoe"  , "slid"  ,  "on"   ,  "the"   ,  "smooth" , "planks."))
paste(s[1], collapse = " ")
#[1] "c(\"The\", \"birch\", \"canoe\", \"slid\", \"on\", \"the\", \"smooth\", \"planks.\")"
```

and

```r
paste(s[[1]], collapse = " ")
#[1] "The birch canoe slid on the smooth planks."
```

This is because `[[` will extract the vector, and `[` and will keep the output as a list.

Comment: Again, as you see it ads a comma between the joined parts of the sentence. The trick I'm looking for is to add the parts of the sentence back so that it looks exactly as it did from the beginning.

Comment: Well, then you can use `paste`

Comment: This code did the trick

paste(s[1], collapse = " ")